# JSON POST request with multiple objects from Java

Tags: java, json, api, post, licensing

I´m traying to verify license keys from Java calling Gumroad API. Gumroad help tells I have to do this call:

```
curl https://api.gumroad.com/v2/licenses/verify
  \ -d "product_permalink=QMGY"
  \ -d "license_key=YOUR_CUSTOMERS_LICENSE_KEY"
  \ -X POST
```

In order to do that from Java, y wrote this code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.gumroad.com/v2/licenses/verify");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    String input = "\"product_permalink=QMGY\"&\"license_key=ABCDEF12-34567890-ABCDEF12-34567890\"";

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(input.getBytes());
    os.flush();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + conn.getResponseCode());
    }
```

But I receive 400 Error or 404 Error depending on how I write the input string. I´m not sure what´s the problem, but I think probably I´m not correctly coding the two -d objects in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

The request is not correct.
First of all you are sending with the Content-Type application/json. However the curl is sending it with application/x-www-form-urlencoded ([see man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d))

There is a also a problem with the data, you are sending:

```
"product_permalink=QMGY"&"license_key=ABCDEF12-34567890"
```

It should be:

```
product_permalink=QMGY&license_key=ABCDEF12-34567890
```

use the following:

```
    String input = "product_permalink=QMGY&license_key=ABCDEF12-34567890-ABCDEF12-34567890";
```

Last you are leaking resources use try-with-resources

Comment: Maybe because the license doesn't exists for the provided product as stated in the response body ???

Comment: Finally I got it! (whith your help, thanks). You were right when told me I had to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but string input must be:          String input = "product_permalink="+URLEncoder.encode("QMGy")+"&license_key="+URLEncoder.encode("ABCDEF12-34567890-ABCDEF12-34567890");